# Hide and show elements in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im having some menu objects, here "link1" and "link2" which I want to toggle some content (forms) on my webpage.

If form1 is visible and I click link2, I want form1 to close and form2 to open.

Relevant jQuery:

```
    $('#link1').click(function(){
        $('#form1:visible').hide();
        $('#form2:visible').hide();
        $('#form1:hidden').show();
    });

    $('#link2').click(function(){
        $('#form1:visible').hide();
        $('#form2:visible').hide();
        $('#form2:hidden').show();
    });
```

Question:
How can I make this simpler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#link1').click(function(){
    $('#form2').hide();
    $('#form1').show();
});

$('#link2').click(function(){
    $('#form1').hide();
    $('#form2').show();
});
```

It hardly gets any simpler. If there's any correlation between the link clicked and the form, like the `1` and `2` in the name, you could condense it into a single function that dynamically gets the right form and shows it... Whether that's any *simpler* is debatable though:

```
$('#link1, #link2').click(function () {
    $('form').hide();
    $('#form' + this.id.substr(-1)).show();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`toggle`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) function which will switch the element between the visible and hidden states:

```
var f1 = $('#form1'), f2 = $('#form2');

$('#link1').click(function(){
    f1.toggle();
    f2.hide();
});

$('#link2').click(function(){
    f1.hide();
    f2.toggle();
});
```

Otherwise, caching the two `#form` selector will help make it slightly more better.

Comment: You may get very different behavior using `toggle`. What if you click a link twice?

Comment: @deceze Oh, I see why the code works differently from the one he gave. That is a rather roundabout way of doing that, yes

Answer (score 0):

You could give them a matching class, but that is pretty simple.

Comment: Could you please enlighten me?

Answer (score 0):

In the HTML:

```
<form id="form1" class="form_group1" ... >
<form id="form2" class="form_group1" ... >
...
<form id="formN" class="form_group2" ... >
```

In javascript:

```
$('#link1').click(function(){
    $('.form_group1').hide();
    $('.form_group2').show();
});

$('#link2').click(function(){
    $('.form_group2').hide();
    $('.form_group1').show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if i got you right, but you have href links, and so when u click link2 you want to open form2 (in case it is not already open), and same process for link1 and form1 ?

what u can do is give a css class for each form and an id , and then:

`$('#link1').click(function(){
    $('#idOform1').css("display","block");
    $('#idOform2').css("display","none");
});`

$('#link2').click(function(){
    $('#idOform2').css("display","block");
    $('#idOform1').css("display","none");
});